Strange behavior of a list manipulation
This is a list of data obtained from numerical calculation, in which the 2nd element in all sublists are the same:
testList = {
{{0.97`, 1.5`, 0.45581534810969593` - 0.00772734024735888` I},
{0.97`, 1.5`, 0.5913019591412524` - 1.4964725754408112` I}},
{{0.975`, 1.5`, 0.4553504163862941` - 0.0062050644396489055` I},
{0.975`, 1.5`, 0.5905962174714036` - 1.4926074278911872` I}},
{{0.98`, 1.5`, 0.45489240813905063` - 0.004689943958019308` I},
{0.98`, 1.5`, 0.5898932208890941` - 1.4887510874114465` I}},
{{0.985`, 1.5`, 0.45444119749032014` - 0.003181966428013874` I},
{0.985`, 1.5`, 0.4553873539373385`},
{0.985`, 1.5`, 0.5891930263200915` - 1.484903661561588` I}},
{{0.99`, 1.5`, 0.45399666192374505` - 0.0016811234165853021` I},
{0.99`, 1.5`, 0.4553777686116016`},
{0.99`, 1.5`, 0.5884956877780517` - 1.4810652565147142` I}},
{{0.995`, 1.5`, 0.4535586680738754` - 0.0001873863571304519` I},
{0.995`, 1.5`, 0.45537510553402233`},
{0.995`, 1.5`, 0.5878012564617705` - 1.4772359769751082` I}},
{{1.`, 1.5`, 0.45312715862725017` + 0.001299216652552471` I},
{1.`, 1.5`, 0.5871097808495345` - 1.4734159261030222` I}}};

I want to take the 1st number and the imaginary part of the 3rd number and group the 2 numbers in a list:
test = Flatten[testList /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, Im[c]}, 2] // Partition[#, 2] &

(*{{0.97, -0.00772734}, {0.97, -1.49647}, {0.975, -0.00620506}, {0.975, -1.49261}, {0.98, -0.00468994}, {0.98, -1.48875}, {0.985, 1.5}, {0.454441 - 0.00318197 I, 0}, {0, -1.4849}, {0.99, 1.5}, {0.453997 - 0.00168112 I, 0}, {0, -1.48107}, {0.995, 1.5}, {0.453559 - 0.000187386 I, 0}, {0, -1.47724}, {1., 0.00129922}, {1., -1.47342}}*)

The above result is unexpected from the 7th to 15th sublist:
(*{0.985, 1.5}, ..., {0, -1.47724}*), for example, where the complex and zero in the 1st element come from in {0.454441 - 0.00318197 I, 0} and {0, -1.4849}. The 7th to 15th sublists are expected to be
{0.985`, - 0.003181966428013874`}, {0.985`, 0}, {0.985`, - 1.484903661561588`}, {{0.99`, - 0.0016811234165853021}, {0.99`, 0},  {0.99`, - 1.4810652565147142`}, {{0.995`, - 0.0001873863571304519`}, {0.995`, 0}, {0.995`, - 1.4772359769751082`}

What did I get wrong? Thank you very much.

Maybe {a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ}, to avoid matching a list of three lists.

Recommendation to OP:  Post this simplest, shortest, clearest minimal case that illustrates you problem.  Do we really need all those digits?  No.

@MichaelE2 do you mean {a_, b_, c_} could match a list of 3 sublists, for example, {{0.985, 1.5, 0.45444119749032014 - 0.003181966428013874 I}, {0.985, 1.5, 0.4553873539373385},{0.985, 1.5, 0.5891930263200915 - 1.484903661561588 I}}? In that case, a_, b_ c_ each can be a list?

@DavidG.Stork thank you for the suggestion. Acutally, I removed most of the data from my real data and not sure whether or not any potential issues would cause the problem. So I just post the data set including different instances, that is, some 2-element lists and some 3-element lists, some with pure real 3rd number and some with complex 3rd number.

Exactly: MatchQ[{{0.985, 1.5,  0.45444119749032014 - 0.003181966428013874  I}, {0.985, 1.5,  0.4553873539373385}, {0.985, 1.5,  0.5891930263200915 - 1.484903661561588  I}}, {a_, b_, c_}]. More generally, {a_, b_, c_} matches a list of any three expressions, whether each of the three is itself a list, number, or any other expression.

@MichaelE2 thank you for the prompt response!

Use Replace instead of ReplaceAll to specify at which level you want the replacement to be made:
Replace[testList, {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, Im[c]}, {2}]~Flatten~1


Some of the lists in testList are 2-element lists and some are 3-element lists. So, your rule is matching those 3-element lists instead of only the lowest level lists. I'd suggest you target your function application more specifically:
Flatten[Map[{#[[1]], Im[#[[3]]]} &, testList, {-2}], 1]

Or you could flatten your input before applying your transformation:
Flatten[testList, {1, 2}] /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, Im[c]}


thank you for your answer. I found Flatten[testList, 1]===Flatten[testList, {1, 2}] gives True. Could you please explain Flatten[testList, {1, 2}], I don't really understand it. Is it Flatten levels 1 and 2?

I should have simplified it before posting. If you're really curious, read the documentation first, and if you still have questions that you want to ask make a new post.
